# How many candies do you get for every 2k, 5k, and 10k egg?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've hatched a few eggs, mostly 5k eggs and some 2k eggs. I believe when you hatch a 5k egg you get 10 candies for that Pokémon. Although, I've looked back on a few Pokémon I've hatched from 5k eggs and found more than 10 candies. I wasn't really paying attention when I hatched my few 2k eggs, so I don't remember how many candies I got.

How many candies do you get for a 2k, 5k and 10k egg? And does it vary with the Pokémon that you hatch, or which incubator you use (infinite or limited)?

Comment: I know after my 10k egg hatched, I had 26 Hitmonchan candies, and that was the first Hitmonchan I ever got.  It's also the only 10k egg I've hatched so far, and I haven't paid much attention to the 2k and 5k eggs to say for certain

Comment: Also to note: the limited use incubators seem to yield higher rewards for both candies and dust compared to the unlimited use incubator.

Comment: @Ekmod I'd be interested in seeing a source on that (especially since I used a limited use incubator on a 2km egg and only got a Zubat... I would have expected at least a Squirtle or something). I thought the only purpose of the limited use incubators was so that you can incubate more than one egg at a time.

Comment: Unfortunately @MageXy, I have no source aside from my (probably small) observed sample. I'm also at work now and can't dig up info to support at the moment. But if someone else wants to see what they can dig up, I'm alright with being wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 2 km eggs:  5 to 15 candy
 5 km eggs: 10 to 21 candy
10 km eggs: 16 to 32 candy
```

Here is a [Reddit Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4ws4dl/results_from_egg_research_egg_distance_does_in/) supporting this claim.

(There was a single report of 4 candy from a 2 km egg but I'm guessing that was a typo/error.)

Comment: I've accepted this answer instead because it has more solid information to back it up.

Answer (score 18):

Each egg will always give you a random amount of candies between 3 and 35. The main difference between the 2KM, 5KM, and 10KM eggs is the possible pokemon that may hatch from them which you can see in this chart:

[image: pokemon go egg hatching chart]

Comment: I have been paying more attention now when hatching my eggs and this is definitely the behavior that I'm seeing. Thanks!

Comment: Too bad a false answer has been marked as correct. The longer distance eggs also give a (at least on average) higher candy output, see Tyler's answer for example.

Answer (score 0):

I've hatched a Hitmonlee and a Onix from 10km eggs. From my Hitmonlee, I got 26 candies and from my Onix, I got 32 candies. I can confirm that my Onix was incubated in a limited-use incubator whereas Hitmonlee was in the infinite-use incubator.

Comment: I don't think that this was due to the incubator type, but instead based off the random candies assigned when hatching eggs as described in the above answers.

Answer (score -2):

It varies based on how many evolutions they have. Less evolutions more candy, more evolutions less candy.