# What is this Pokémon Go event I've heard about?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been hearing about a Pokémon Go event that's happening this week for Halloween. What exactly is going to happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [official Pokémon site](http://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-news/halloween-treats-in-pokemon-go/), there will be many bonuses for players who play Pokémon Go between October 26th and November 1st (it looks like it's safe to assume UTC, based on [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/59ahix/halloween_event_does_not_start_at_your_local_time/), which says the event has not started in New Zealand yet, despite being October 26th there, as well as noting the fact that Ingress events used UTC), mostly revolving around candy.

- Transferring Pokémon will reward you with 2 candies instead of 1.
- Catching Pokémon will reward you with 6 candies instead of 3.
- Hatching Pokémon will reward you with double the candy you would normally receive. For reference, an answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276005/how-many-candies-do-you-get-for-every-2k-5k-and-10k-egg) says that you will normally get 5-15 candy for a 2km egg, 10-21 candy for a 5km egg, and 16-32 candy for a 10km egg. **This means that during this event, you will receive 10-30 candy for every 2km egg, 20-42 candy for every 5km egg, and 32-64 candy for every 10km egg.**
- Buddy Pokémon will find candy 4x as fast as they normally do. (0.25km, 0.75km, and 1.25km instead of 1km, 3km, and 5km)

In addition to the above candy bonuses, Pokémon in the Drowzee, Gastly, and Zubat lines will be more common during this event. The full list of Pokémon is:

- Drowzee
- Hypno
- Gastly
- Haunter
- Gengar
- Zubat
- Golbat

In addition to those listed above, some unannounced Pokémon are spawning much more frequently, namely Meowth and the Cubone line, which include:

- Meowth
- Cubone
- Marowak

Aside from personal experience, [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/59eer4/huge_increase_in_cubone_and_meowth_spawns_during/) and [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/59edfa/cubone_and_meowth_also_more_common_during/) express the same thing.

Note: Apparently, Persian is not a Halloween Pokémon, even though Meowth is. [This post](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/halloween-guide) has a list of Halloween Pokémon that does not include Persian. (Anecdotally, I have not encountered a single wild Persian during this event)

Comment: Lol, we are overhelmed by Drowzees all the year in our city :D

Comment: @AntoineHejlík maybe I'll finally get a Hypno :P

Comment: Is it just my area or cubones and Marowaks are also increased in spawn rates ?

Comment: @Karlyr it's happening to me where I am as well, so I think that was an unannounced bonus... If I find a source, I'll add it to my answer!

Comment: I mean, it does make sense in a lore POV. First time I ever saw a cubone this morning, something HAD to be happening :p

Comment: @Karlyr True. I guess Meowth is as close as they could get to a black cat. Too bad it's not the Alolan Meowth!

Comment: Nice thinking with the black cat. Had no clue why Meowth would even be there.

Comment: Persian is (from most anecdotal evidence I've seen) not spawning more. For some reason it hasn't been included as an evolved line of one of the spooky pokemon that's spawning more despite Meowth spawning a lot more.