# Which Pokémon have higher spawn rates during the Valentine's Day Event?

Tags: pokemon-go

Niantic posted information on their [Valentine's Day](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/valentines2017) event that is taking place. In the post, they mention a few Pokémon who will have increased spawn rates

> Throughout the celebration, you’ll notice that Chansey, Clefable, and many other adorable pink Pokémon will be encountered more frequently in the wild.

Which other Pokémon fall other the "*many other adorable pink Pokémon*" category?

Also, as we saw during the [Halloween event](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289196/what-is-this-pok%C3%A9mon-go-event-ive-heard-about), there were undocumented Pokémon who had an increased spawn rate. Are there any undocumented Pokémon in this event who have an increased spawn rate?

Comment: This isn't a complete answer but I've **definitely** seen way more Exeggcute than normal and three Lickitung spawns since you posted this question.

Comment: @Vemonus I've seen an increase in those, in addition to Slowpokes. I think Niantic has a misconception of the word "adorable"

Comment: @Wondercricket And "Pink", for that matter...

Comment: @Margaret Pink is actually well-defined in this context and the observed data fits that definition. The main series Pokedex has an option to sort for color and one of the colors is Pink. This group includes several Pokemon that are not exclusively pink, but apparently considered to be "mainly pink".

Comment: I have caught more exeggcutes than anything else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it's still quite early in this weeklong event, [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5svm8j/valentines_day_event_guide_porygon_blissey_and/) has listed confirmed spawns not explicitly mentioned by Niantic.

Aside from Clefairy and Chansey, which were mentioned in the official announcement, it appears that the following pink Pokémon have been confirmed to have increased spawns:

- Clefable
- Porygon
- Lickitung
- Exeggcute
- Jigglypuff
- Wigglytuff
- Slowpoke
- Slowbro

In addition to these, there are also increased odds to hatch Cleffa, Igglybuff, and Smoochum from eggs obtained during this event.

Comment: It is intriguing how Porygon made it to the list, seeing how it is only partially pink, but I'm not complaining.

Answer (score 5):

The statement is most probably hinting at the Pokemon's official Pokedex color listing. [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_color#Pink) lists the following Pokemon in the Pink category that are also available in Pokemon Go:

- Clefairy
- Clefable
- Jigglypuff
- Wigglytuff
- Slowpoke
- Slowbro
- Exeggcute
- Lickitung
- Chansey
- Mr. Mime
- Porygon
- Cleffa
- Igglybuff
- Smoochum

Since these have officially the color pink, we should expect these and only these to be affected. Mr. Mime, being a region exclusive Pokemon, will still only appear in Europe.

Comment: Mew is in there as well -  *very wishfull thinking*

Comment: I've seen a Mr. Mime defending a gym in Downtown Crossing, Boston - the trainer must have obtained it in Europe?

Comment: @Mathias711 That is true. I left it out, though, because it's not currently available.

Comment: @pjmorse Either that, or the trainer could be a European visitor (those are the 100% legit options). Or a friend could have logged into his account from Europe to catch one (that's the questionable option). Or he could have spoofed his GPS location to trick the app into thinking he's in Europe (that's the blatant cheating option). Either way, the Mr. Mime was caught in Europe according to the GPS location.